# How to configure the local RHEL server as NTP Server

Tags: ntp

I am trying to configure local RHEL server as NTP Server. But the "ntpstat" showing unsynchronised.

**Local host ip address : 192.168.1.122**

**/etc/ntp.conf**

server 192.168.1.122 prefer # local clock

fudge 192.168.1.122 stratum 10

**ntpstat output**

unsynchronised time server re-starting

polling server every 8 s

**ntpq -p**

" remote refid st t when poll reach delay offset jitter

englabnia2.lab. .INIT. 16 u - 64 0 0.000 0.000 0.000

**ntp.log**

26 Oct 16:20:12 ntpd[11361]: ntpd exiting on signal 15

26 Oct 16:20:12 ntpd[11562]: inappropriate address 192.168.1.122 for the fudge command, line ignored

26 Oct 16:20:12 ntpd[11562]: 0.0.0.0 c016 06 restart

26 Oct 16:20:12 ntpd[11562]: 0.0.0.0 c012 02 freq_set kernel 0.000 PPM

26 Oct 16:20:12 ntpd[11562]: 0.0.0.0 c011 01 freq_not_set

**ntpq as**

ntpq> as

ind assid status conf reach auth condition last_event cnt

1 43525 8011 yes no none reject mobilize 1 ntpq>

Note : The NTP service is running on VM and it's not connected to internet. So am using local clock as reference. But it's not at all synchronising.

**Keys are configured in /ntp/keys**

id type key

1 M 1234

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: All the answer is there: http://lists.ntp.org/pipermail/questions/2003-November/001507.html

Comment: Thanks @A.B . The provided link commands are working fine in our environment. Thanks again.